# Retrieve array items that contain a particular string

Tags: java, arrays, jsoup

I have a bunch of URLs like below

Contact

How do I return just "www.example.com" ?

Is there an easy to do this through jsoup?

I have relative and absolute urls and I just want to retrieve them without the tags.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through your array and test each entry with the below example.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");

for(String x : myArray){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    int count = m.groupCount();  
    while(count > 0){ 
         System.out.println(m.group(count--));
    }

}
```

[Matcher Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with this solution based on the given answer :

```
for (Element link: hrefTags)
{
    absUrl = link.absUrl("href");//Retrieves all URLs
    System.out.println(absUrl);
}
```

Comment: You should accept this since it solves your problem, so the thread can be considered closed.